# Getting an array of every string that matches a Regular expression

Tags: java, arrays, regex

How would I parse a file like this:

```
Item costs $15 and is made up of --Metal--
Item costs $64 and is made up of --Plastic--
```

I can do

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
String result = m.group();
```

But how would I get EVERY result?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex); 
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
while(m.find()){
    matches.add(m.group());
}
```